# Changing column names or exceptions to strsplit

Tags: r

I have a dataframe Genotypes and it has columns of loci labeled D2S1338, D2S1338.1, CSF1PO, CSF1PO.1, Penta.D, Penta.D.1.  These names were automatically generated when I imported the Excel spreadsheet into R such that the for the two columns labeled CSF1PO, the column with the first set of alleles was labeled CSF1PO and the second column was labeled CSF1PO.1.  This works fine until I get to Penta D which was listed with a space in Excel and imported as Penta.D.  When I apply the following code, Penta.D gets combined with Penta.C and Penta.E to give me nonsensical results:

```
locuses = unique(unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(Freqs), ".", fixed=TRUE), function(x) x[1]))) 
Expected <- sapply(locuses, function(x) 1 - sum(unlist(Freqs[grepl(x, names(Freqs))])^2))
```

This code works great for all loci except the Pentas because of how they were automatically names.  How do I either write an exception for the strsplit at Penta.C, Penta.D, and Penta.E or change these names to PentaC, PentaD, and PentaE so that the above code works as expected?  I run the following line:

```
Genotypes <- transform(Genotypes, rename.vars(Genotypes, from="Penta.C", to="PentaC", info=TRUE))
```

and it tells me:

```
Changing in Genotypes             
From: Penta.C
To:   PentaC
```

but when I view Genotypes, it still has my Penta loci written as Penta.C.  I thought this function would write it back to the original data frame, not just a copy.  What am I missing here?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you use a function such as `rename.vars` that is not a base function, you should start your code section with `library(name_of_package)`

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code is splitting the variable names by . and extracting the first piece. It sounds like you instead want to split by . and extract all the pieces except for the last one:

```
locuses = unique(unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(Freqs), ".", fixed=TRUE),
                               function(x) paste(x[1:(length(x)-1)], collapse=""))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This does fix my Penta problem but it now tacks on the allele number (e.g. 12 or 10.3) after the decimal I was trying to remove as well as the .1 for the 2nd column of alleles.  Is there a way to create this so if there is a letter after the first decimal it is pasted and if it is a number, it is not pasted?  I've tried this: locuses = unique(unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(Freqs), ".", fixed=TRUE), function(x) is.character(paste(x[1:(length(x)-1)]), collapse="")))) and it gives me an error that 2 arguments are passed to is.character which requires 1.

Comment: Here is a sample of what locuses returns: [1] "AMEL"      "CSF1PO"    "D10S1248"  "D12S391"  
  [5] "D12S39117" "D12S39118" "D12S39119" "D12S39120"
  [9] "D12S39122" "D12S39124" "D13S317"   "D16S539" So it adds the allele number onto D12S391 (17, 18, 19, 20, 22, 24) but seems to skip some alleles and some loci entirely (CSF1PO, D10S1248, D13S317).  I'm not sure if there is a rhyme or reason to this that could help me remove the unwanted information from all of the loci as expected.

Comment: I wound up just editing my excel spreadsheet to remove the space between Penta and C.  Once I reimported and reran the rest of my code, it worked fine.  Thanks for your input though and I'll keep in mind including example inputs and expected outputs in the original post in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to remove ".n" where n is a single digit if and only if it appears at the end of a line.

```
loci.columns <- read.table(header=F, 
                           text="D2S1338,D2S1338.1,CSF1PO,CSF1PO.1,Penta.D,Penta.D.1", 
                           sep=",")

loci <- gsub("\\.\\d$",replace="",unlist(loci.columns))
loci
# [1] "D2S1338" "D2S1338" "CSF1PO"  "CSF1PO"  "Penta.D" "Penta.D"
loci <- unique(loci)
loci
# [1] "D2S1338" "CSF1PO"  "Penta.D"
```

In `gsub(...)`, `\\.` matches ".", `\\d` matches any digit, and `$` forces the match to be at the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem seems like the names are being made "valid" on import by the `make.names` function

```
> make.names("Penta C")
[1] "Penta.C"
```

Avoid R's column re-naming with use of the `check.names=FALSE` argument to `read.table`. If you refer explicitly to columns you'll need to provide a back-quoted strings

```
df$`Penta C`
```